# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'connectOutlet' of undefined

Tags: ember.js

I'm getting an undefined parent View for my loading route handler -- but only when a specific page is navigated to first in my application.

http://www.sentinel21.com/#/posts

If you visit the about page first or the root, the loading handler seems to load properly.  I'm not sure what I'm doing to cause the loading route to render improperly in that case.

Here's the loading route.

```
App.LoadingRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    renderTemplate: function(){
        this.render('loading', {
            outlet: "loading",
            into: "application"
        });
    }
});
```

My application template has this code.

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="column row"></div>
  {{outlet "loading"}}
  {{outlet}}
</div>
```

All the code is available on [github](https://github.com/aarongundel/sentinel21/tree/master/public/templates), and that's probably the easiest place to see the templates, which are precompiled.

Comment: I'm guessing you've seen this? http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/found-a-fun-hidden-loading-feature/1677 
 
I don't think you need to hard code rendering the template and the outlet.

Comment: I would not normally need to -- but I want the loading template to render in a specific place in my application template.

Comment: Dunno if you've seen that Ember 1.2 Beta improved the loading route, adding nested loading routes: http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/proposal-nested-loading-routes/2895. 

ENV = {
  FEATURES: {
    'ember-routing-loading-error-substates': true
  }
};

Comment: Thanks Hana, that's really good to see.  I think this will go a long way to fixing my problem when it's out.  Appreciate you looking into it further.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem, and it was because my app template was named "app.handlebars" but should have been called "application.handlebars". Once I changed it, the outlet was found and everything worked as expected.

Comment: Had a similar spelling mistake that led to this error. 'appliction' is not the same as 'application'. :(